# ocr implementation in tensorflow

Tags: image, python-2.7, tensorflow, ocr

My requirement is i need to read OCR text from the image(jpg) using tensorflow. 
I tried by downloading the below project and tried to execute the code.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr

I am able to execute the train.py but unable to test the complete flow. I want to train and test 100 sample images. Could anybody share detail insight how to take it further.

FYI:
Earlier i used the pytesser API but the accuracy was very low. It was not able to read text of various sizes.

Answer (score 2):

To test a model on the FSNS dataset run

```
python eval.py --dataset_name=fsns --split_name=test
```

it will run the evaluation for --num_batches (default 100) times --batch_size images (default 32).

if you want to test it on your own data you have three options:

1. Convert it into the [same format as FSNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430310/how-to-create-dataset-in-the-same-format-as-the-fsns-dataset/44461910#44461910) and define mynewdatasetname.py by reusing [fsns.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr#how-to-use-your-own-image-data-to-train-the-model)
2. Don't convert the data, but write a custom dataset file similar to the fsns.py (see the [get_split](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3eba37c/attention_ocr/python/datasets/fsns.py#L104) function
3. Write a custom script to [export](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md) the trained model and a custom eval script/app to do the evaluation. Here are [some tips for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45042252/743658)

Please note that the Attention OCR model trained on the FSNS will be able to transcribe street name signs in France, not just random text.